@Published array property doesn't trigger the view to redraw
I have a SwiftUI view structure where the parent view uses a @StateObject for its LeaveViewModel, and this view model contains a @Published array. When I modify an existing element in the array, the child view that observes the view model does not update as expected. The same happens also when I create a new one and try to append.
Here is some code:
Parent View
struct LeaveView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = LeaveViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        MyRequestsView(viewModel: viewModel)
    }
}

Child View
struct MyRequestsView: View {

 // MARK: - Property wrappers

 @ObservedObject var viewModel: LeaveViewModel

 
var body: some View {
 ForEach(viewModel.leaveRequests) { leave in
  NavigationLink {
    LeaveRequestDetailView(leaveRequest: leave) { request in
      Task {
        await viewModel.createNewLeaveRequest(with: request)
      }
    }
  } label: {
    LeaveRequestRow(leaveRequest: leave)
  }
}

and the view model => LeaveViewModel
/// Properties
@Published var leaveRequests: [LeaveRequest] = [] /// Conform to Identifable

/// Methods
@MainActor
func createNewLeaveRequest(with request: LeaveRequestDTO) async {
    isLoading = true
    defer { isLoading = false }
    do {
        let leave = try await service.createNewLeaveRequest(with: request)
        leaveRequests.append(leave.data)
    } catch {
      ////
    }
}

What might be causing the view not to update when a new item is appended or modified in the @Published array?

I don't understand what's going on in cancel leave request. You are getting an index of something that exists in the leaveRequests array and setting it to the same leaveRequest.. Unless I'm missing something that's not a change. perhaps you should just be calling objectWillChange not sure what you're trying for there..

Hi @user20325868. I've updated my code, the problem is still the same and no the objectWillChange method will not trigger the redraw as well
